# If $A\in M_2(\mathbb R)$ with eigenvalues $a,b>0$ then $\exists B:\ B^2=A$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be a $2\times2$ real matrix with eigenvalues  $a,b>0$. Show that there exists a matrix $B\in M_2(\mathbb R)$ such that $B^2=A$. Is this statement true if $a<0$ or $b<0$ ?

My attempt : since $a,b$ are eigenvalues, we have
\begin{align}
(A-aI)(A-bI)=0.
\end{align}
If $B^2=A$ then
\begin{align}
0&=(B^2-aI)(B^2-bI)
\\ &=(B-\sqrt aI)(B+\sqrt aI)(B-\sqrt bI)(B+\sqrt bI).
\end{align}
Now, if I set $B=\sqrt a I$, will this imply $B^2=A$ ? Is there some tricks that I can use here ? I hope someone would give me some hints for this problem. Thanks.

Comment: You tagged eigenvalues/eigenvectors.  How about trying to use them?

Comment: @TedShifrin do you mean there exists $u,v\ne0:\ Au=au,\ Av=bv$, so we consider $B= \Big[ a[u]\ \ b[v]\Big]$ ?

Comment: The statement is clear if $A$ is diagonalizable (that is, if $A$ is a scalar multiple of the identity or if $a \ne b$). Indeed, if $A=PDP^{-1}$, then the required $B$ is just $P\sqrt{D}P^{-1}$ (where $\sqrt{D}$ is the diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries are the square roots of those of $D$). It remains to also consider the non-diagonalizable case (which could happen only if $a=b$).

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang oh thanks, that's really nice idea